# edit/delete table data without gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am new at asp.net and I have to do a research publications app. I have a table which displays data from database. I don't want to use gridview because i need to display table as in template  and because I want to edit abstract of an article and I cant display all abstract in table (because abstract may be big).  What I want to do is when click "delete" icon that I have in my table to delete all information of that specific row and when click "edit" icon to go to another page which has a form filled with data that get from database for that specific row and perform a simple update. In php i know how to do it by id but here I dont kno how to select a row and get the id.

This is code what i tried :

```
public partial class Edit_Delete : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //open connection with database
                connection.Open();

                //query to select all users with the given username
                command.CommandText = "select * from artikulli";

                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {                     
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            sb.Append("<tr>");
                            sb.Append("<td>");
                            sb.Append(rd[1].ToString());
                            sb.Append("</td>");                               
                            sb.Append("<td>");
                            sb.Append(rd[3].ToString());
                            sb.Append("</td>");
                            sb.Append("<td>");
                            sb.Append("<input type='image' src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'>");
                            sb.Append(" <input type='image' src='images/icn_trash.png' title='Trash'>");                                         
                            sb.Append("</td>");
                            sb.Append("</tr>");

                        }                     

                    }

                }
                Row1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //open connection with database
                connection.Open();

                //query to select all users with the given username
                command.CommandText = "delete from artikulli ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating table in code, use DataList or Repease ASP.NET controls.
Here you can specify your own design template, and can bind event handlers to handle your edit and delete button/linkButton/imageButton events

For more information see:

- [Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls (VB)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb)
- [Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498210.aspx)
- [How to use DataList control in ASP.NET using C#](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-use-datalist-control-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1036.aspx)

Comment: but I want to do sth else. I want to perform an update by clicking edit icon and go in an other page which has fields prefilled with values from db , and I want to get id of a row and perform update query. How to do this?

Comment: Are you open to switch to DataList or Repeater controls, or do you want to do all the plumbing yourself. What you want can be achieved both ways. If you wish to learn how ASP.NET Page framework works under-the-hood, your current approach is good, but if your target to is to complete these pages, efficiently and quickly, DataList and Repeater should be your choice.

Comment: ok thank you, but the second tutorial made me a little confused :/

Comment: The concept is, you will bind the primary key of the table as CommandArgument of the imageButton or linkButton (for edit or delete); Also, the respective button will also have a CommandName set (like "ed" and "del"). In the event handler, you will retrieve the primary key using e.CommandArgument, and the button pressed using e.CommandName. Then if it is a delete command (e.CommandName == "del") you will run the query to delete that record from the table and bind the DataList/Repeater again.

Comment: Likewise, if the command is "ed" you will navigate to the other page, passing the row's primary key value (e.CommandArgument) using queryString or sessionState. This second page will load the record values based on the primary key value received and populate those values in respective textboxes/comboBoxes/lists/etc on the page.